# unwindsegue - app crash (commitEditingStyle interrupted)?

Tags: ios

I have a tableView where the user can swipe(left) to delete data entries.  If the user swipe left, and then instead of tapping delete (or "unswipe" right), the user tap the unwindSegueButton, the app crash in AppDelegate.

The crash happens in the viewController I am rewinding to. It fully loads, but then crash. If the user commit to delete or "unswipe" first, there is no crash...

How can I avoid this ?  Can I do something in prepareforsegue that undo the left swipe?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let source = objectSample[indexPath.row].source.name

    return source == "MyApp"
}


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let source = objectSample[indexPath.row].source.name
        //println(objectSample[indexPath.row].UUID)

            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) && (source == "MyApp") {
                let UUIDtoDelete = objectSample[indexPath.row].UUID
                println("Deleted entry: \(source)")
                deleteUUIDobject(UUIDtoDelete)
                objectSample.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

            }else {
            println("Not allowed to delete, source: \(source)")
        }
    }
```

> AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let isOnboarded = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("Onboarded")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // instantiate your desired ViewController
    let dashboardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! UIViewController
    let onboardingViewControllerOne = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingVCOne") as! UIViewController
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavigationController") as! UINavigationController

    if (isOnboarded) {
            window!.rootViewController = navigationController 
        }else{
            window!.rootViewController = onboardingViewControllerOne
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get in the console? Have you tried using breakpoints?

Comment: Plz put up the crash log.

Comment: @cecexx If the user commit to delete or "unswipe" first, there is no crash

Comment: @VivekMolkar The crash happens in the viewController I am rewinding to.  It fully loads, but then crash.  If the user commit to delete or "unswipe" first, there is no crash...

Comment: Try to use an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to help you figure out where the crash is happening exactly

Comment: The crash happened in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the crash by adding the code below, but I wish I knew why the crash happens in the first place.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }
```